# iPhone Sensor Data

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

Can iPhone sensor usage data (Accelerometer, Gyro, GPS, etc,) be exported to a computer for further analysis?

Comment: Could you expand a little on your question? Are you hoping to find an app that does this? Are you wanting to develop an app to do this yourself?

Comment: No I want to transfer directly from my iPhone to PC. I would be using that data for analysis. I would prefer if the data is stored as .csv file.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this using just the phone on its own. I think you'd need an app to gather the data and send it somewhere.

Comment: Oh, so you know any app which can me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of Apps can do this, I have tried sensorLoc, which can save sensor data into csv files, and send to computer through email or UDP. It is free.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few different iOS apps that will do what you are looking for.

An example is [Sensor Data](http://wavefrontlabs.com/Wavefront_Labs/Sensor_Data.html) from Warefront Labs.

- gathers data from the accelerometer, the gyro (on supported models) and the GPS.
- can export to CSV
- can stream over UDP to another computer for realtime capture